# What is the minimum number of vertices a graph must have to have two triangles, two 3-independent sets, or one of each?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am trying to figure out what the minimum number of vertices a graph must have in order guarantee that it has two triangles (3-cliques), two 3-independent sets, or one of each. Two cliques or independent sets are different if they differ by at least one vertex.

My initial thought is that the answer is 12, since Ramsey's theorem tells us that a complete graph with 6 vertices will have a 3-clique or a 3-independent set ($R(3,3)=6$). Combining two 6 vertex complete graphs will guarantee the existence of two 3-cliques or 3-independent sets. What I'm not sure of is whether this is the *minimum* or just an upper bound on the minimum.

Comment: Your formulation "a complete graph with $6$ vertices will have a $3$-clique or a $3$-independent set" is sloppy and does not express what you mean. (A *complete* graph on $6$ vertices contains a $3$-clique, indeed a $6$-clique, and no $3$-independent clique. Please edit your post to say what you mean, e,g,, you  could just delete "complete". (According to Polya, the traditional mathematics instructot writes A, says B, means C, but it shoukd be D.)

Comment: By the way, one of the ways of showing that $R(3,3)\le6$ is by proving directly that, in an edge-coloring of $K_6$ with two colors, the minimum possible number of monochromatic triangles is $2$.

Comment: Please could you clarify your question? The answer to your question as it stands is 4 --- there is at least one 4-node graph (but no 3-node graph) with at least one of the three properties you list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint / Well known fact:** Show that any complete graph on 6 vertices whose edges are colored with 2 colors has 2 monochromatic triangles.

Comment: I added the word "complete". Apologies, in Ramsey Theory, usually the graphs are complete.